# jQuery floating menu in wordpress is not working with content part

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In wordpress I have developed a website. In that I have two sidebars. In the left sidebar I have the wordpress custom menu. So as the page is scrolled down I want the left sidebar menu to be at fixed position so I just used this jQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {  
  var top = jQuery('.widget_nav_menu').offset().top - parseFloat(jQuery('.widget_nav_menu').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  //console.log(top);
  jQuery(window).scroll(function(event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    //console.log(y);
    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      jQuery('.widget_nav_menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      jQuery('.widget_nav_menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

This is working fine when I have something above my menu. But if there is only menu then the content is floating part is merging over the menu. Now when you will go to [this live  site](http://modulesoft.info/projects/valuepayroll/) you can see the actual issue.
In this site when you will go to payroll software page and will scroll the page, you can see the left menus will be fixed at top part as I have used jQuery. Here it is okay. But when you will go to the free trail or buy page and will scroll down the page then you can see the main content part is merging over the menu. So can someone kindly help me to solve this? Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

**Note**
When visiting the site if it shows 500 error then just refresh the page it will work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a transparent border to the `#teritary` div style, defined at line 1673 in your `wp-content/themes/ValuePayroll/style.css` file:

```
#teritary {
  width: 230px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  border: solid 1px transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your left sidebar has an only child `<aside>` and it disappears on your **main content** container if the aside tag is set to fixed, thus the `#inner-page` div will shift to the left. You have to find a way such that there would still be an `<aside>` tag (or any tag will serve as dummy) to maintain the width of the left sidebar and prevent the content from moving once your class `.fixed` is applied by JS.

But that is an ugly way to do it. Another way I could think of (which is better) is to add a **left margin** to your `#inner-page` div as soon as the `.fixed` class is applied, equivalent to the width of your left sidebar. Though this I think would affect other pages when there is other `<aside>` tags that isn't `.fixed` resulting to shifting the content farther to the right - workaround is, add a conditional statement such that if only one `<aside>` tag existed under your left sidebar, only this margin-left is called.

Roughly so:

```
if (y >= top) {
  jQuery('.widget_nav_menu').addClass('fixed', function(){

  //inserted, fine tune this to a working code, untested
    if ( $('#teritary aside:only-child').length ) {
    $("#inner-page").css("margin-left", "250px");
    }
  //or you can omit this else statement
  else { $("#inner-page").css("margin-left", "0"); } 

});
} else {
  // otherwise remove it
  jQuery('.widget_nav_menu').removeClass('fixed');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say this is possible in CSS using the property `position: fixed` I don't think it requires Jquery. I'm only viewing on mobile so I may not see the full size view.